# How do I export a minified CSS file using client-side less.js?

Tags: javascript, css, client-side, less, minify

I have a web project I'm working on and it is using LESS to combine all the files into one CSS for me. However I obviously don't want the client side javascript to have to run in production as that is going to slow things down.

Is there a way with the **client-side** less.js that it can export the .less files you give it to a single CSS file, which I could then call in my live environment?

Comment: You need to install nodeJS and run the compile.js provided in your less utils directory (in command line)

Comment: Is there not a non command line equivalent? Would be much easier to have it do it as I preview what I've done rather than having to keep running a command.

Comment: Maybe, but not one I know of ...

Comment: Did either of the answers help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options for this that I know of:

1. Use the [LESS command line tool](http://lesscss.org/#-server-side-usage)
2. If you're on a Mac, use [LESS.app](http://incident57.com/less/)

Running a watch command isn't that big of a deal, it becomes second nature quite quickly :)

Comment: From what I have seen there is no way to export the CSS from the client side less.js library. So I'm accepting this answer as the LESS command line option is suggested with the original documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want a non-command line option, I'd recommend [LESS.app](http://incident57.com/less/) if you're running OS X. If not, try [Simpless](http://wearekiss.com/simpless) (cross-platform) or [Crunch](http://crunchapp.net/) (Adobe Air-based).

PS. They're all free!